# How to get an image using IHTMLSelectionObject?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

You can get text doing the following:

```
    IHTMLSelectionObject selection = htmlDocument.selection;

    IHTMLTxtRange range = selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
```

However if I select an image it does not copy the image tag. If you select an image how do get it to return `<img..>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out the answer.

Its really simple:

```
IHTMLSelectionObject selection = htmlDocument.selection;

IHTMLTxtRange range = selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
string html = range.htmlText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for Pascal syntax:

```
var
  Selection: IHTMLSelectionObject;
  CtlRange: IHTMLControlRange;
  ImgElement: IHTMLImgElement;

Selection:=(WB.Document as IHTMLDocument2).selection;
if Selection.type_ = 'Control' then
begin
  CtlRange:=Selection.createRange as IHTMLControlRange;
  ImgElement:=CtlRange.item(0);
  // FileName:=ImgElement.src;
end;
```